# How to I read in a String as a date?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a simple block of code as follows which takes in a date using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), creates a Date object and spits it out textually again

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
Date date = dateformat.parse("23/10/2014 14:00");
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

I was expecting `date.toString()` to spit out a similar representation of the date I'd entered, but instead I this: `Mon Dec 30 14:00:00 GMT 2013` which **isn't the same date at all** as I typed in. (though the time *is* the same correct.)

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm happy with the format coming out, but the problem is that it's definitely a different date to the one I entered!

Comment: Little 'y' for year.

Comment: `YYYY` means "week-year". You want `yyyy`.

Comment: Yes, the year from Y to y fixes the issue. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing a little y for year fixes the issue, and the output changes to

`Thu Oct 23 14:00:00 BST 2014`

- Y represents Week year
- y represents Year

The code now reads

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = dateformat.parse("23/10/2014 14:00");
System.out.println(date.toString());
```